# pass date to c# function from javascript method

Tags: javascript, c#

I am calling a c# function that returns a `FileContentResult`. However, the date is not being passed as a parameter to the `c#` function and always shows as `null`. what am i missing:

Javascript code:

```
function exportResponses()
{  
     window.location = "/Blah/ExportResponse?
        questionnaireID=0&clinicID=0&responseStartDate='19/10/2019'";
}
```

C# function

```
public FileContentResult ExportResponse(
     int questionnaireID = 0,
     int clinicID = 0, 
     DateTime? responseStartDate=null)
{

}
```

Comment: Do non-zero values of the other parameters arrive?

Comment: Try sending your date as a string to your `Controller` method: `public FileContentResult ExportResponse(int questionnaireID = 0, int clinicID = 0, string responseStartDate=null)`, and then you can process the string value accordingly in your method.

Comment: this worked. if you answer it, i will accept it.

Comment: Can you try a date format of "yyyy-MM-dd", so "2019-10-19"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to your problem, you would have to send your date as a string to your `Controller` method:

```
public FileContentResult ExportResponse(int questionnaireID = 0, int clinicID = 0, string responseStartDate=null)
```

And then you can process the string value accordingly in your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the date in the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (i.e. use [`Date().toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) before passing to the view).

Comment: i get this error: SCRIPT5001: SCRIPT5001: Number expected. this is what i wrote: new Date(responseStartDate).toISOString()

Comment: It's hard to tell whether you're actually passing the value. Are you sure that `responseStartDate` is populated when you pass it to the `Date` constructor?

Comment: yes i run an alert to confirm that. the value however is passed like this: 19/10/2019. i ran against the link you provided and it breaks there as well

Comment: @Baahubali possibly it is interpreting that date-string as MM/dd/yyyy and so fails over "month 19"

Comment: yes i agree but there is no easy way for me to convert it dd/mm/yyyy format

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
function exportResponses()
{  
      var startDate = new Date('10/10/2019').toISOString();
      window.location = "/SMS/ExportResponse?
      questionnaireID=0&clinicID=0&responseStartDate="+startDate ;
}
```

And in your c# function try parsing parameter `responseStartDate` into `DateTime` in your required format.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(responseStartDate, "yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: you are telling me the same as what @Den has answered below. However, it's not working. i am using IE 11.

Comment: That toISOString returns a format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'`, so ParseExact will not accept it with your format

Answer (score 0):

try to separate the date to days, month and year, because is not good practice to use "/" in URL variables.

you try something like this :

```
window.location = "/SMS/ExportResponse?
      questionnaireID=0&clinicID=0&day="+startDate.day+"&month="+startDate.month+"&year="+startDate.year
```

Comment: how do you separate them out? like manually first 2 characters are dates etc?

Comment: Just Split by / or -